# Determinant as a measure of instability of a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, determinant

Suppose we have a system of linear algebraic equations defined by
$Ax=B$,
where $A$ is $n\times n$ real matrix and $B$ is $n\times 1$ column. Judging by the $\det A$ how can we determine the extent of how stable the given system is? For example, if $\det A<10^{-p}$ can we conclude that the system is susceptible to changes in $k(p)$-th digit after the decimal point, or that changes after $k_1(p)$-th digit after the decimal would entail changes in solution after $k_2(p)$-th digit? What would be the rule for $k_{1,2}(p)$ here?

Answer (score 1):

It's dangerous to use a determinant as a measure of condition number for your system. 
Scaling the matrix A does not change the condition number of the system while it does change the determinant of A! In fact, determinants are only a measure for the absolute pertubartion of the solution. Therefor, no general conclusion about how many decimals will be lost, can be made.

NB: be careful not to confuse the conditioning of a problem with the stability of an algorithm.

Comment: Oh, see. What would be the way to assess the conditioning of a problem then? When scaling, absolute values of elements in the matrix also grow. Maybe it somehow lies in ratio of the absolute value of elements to the absolute value of determinant?